# Why does it take longer to dump and load with pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL?

Tags: python, pickle

I test three different protocols with pickle; 0, 1, 2.

In my test I dumped and loaded one `dict` of about 270000 (`int`, `int`) pairs and one `set` with about 560000 `int`.

Following is my testing code (you can safely skip the two fetch functions which I used to fetch data from database):

```
protocol = 0 # Tested 0, 1, and 2
print 'Protocol:', protocol
t0 = time.time()
sku2spu_dict = fetch_sku2spu_dict()
pid_set = fetch_valid_pids()
t1 = time.time()
print 'Time in sql:', t1 - t0
pickle.dump(sku2spu_dict, open('sku.pcike_dict', 'w'), protocol)
pickle.dump(pid_set, open('pid.picke_set', 'w'), protocol)
t2 = time.time()
print 'Time in dump:', t2 - t1
sku2spu_dict = pickle.load(open('sku.pcike_dict', 'r'))
pid_set = pickle.load(open('pid.picke_set', 'r'))
t3 = time.time()
print 'Time in load:', t3 - t2
```

And following is the time spent by each one:

```
Protocol: 0
Time in dump: 31.3491470814
Time in load: 29.8991980553

Protocol: 1
Time in dump: 32.3191611767
Time in load: 20.6666529179

Protocol: 2
Time in dump: 94.2163629532
Time in load: 42.7647490501
```

To my great surprise, protocol 2 is MUCH worse than 0 and 1.

However, the dumped file size is the smallest with protocol 2, which is about half of protocol 0 and 1.

In the documentation, it says:

> Protocol version 2 was introduced in Python 2.3. It provides much more efficient pickling of new-style classes.

And for the definition of `new-style classes`, it says:

> Any class which inherits from object. This includes all built-in types like list and dict

So I expected protocol 2 to be faster in dumping and loading objects.

Anyone know why?

**UPDATE：**

Problem solved after replacing `pickle` with `cPickle`.

Now `load` and `dump` take 5 and 3 seconds with protocol 2, whereas protocol 0 and 1 takes more than 10 seconds.

Comment: Out of interest, what was your methodology for timing? Wherever a question involves execution speed, it's generally best to give everything someone needs to run a test themselves.

Comment: That kind of test isn't very accurate, instead take a look at [the ``timeit`` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html).

Comment: @Lattyware I think the difference is too HUGE to be ignored by `time`.

Comment: It's more about ``timeit`` running the test multiple times to check it's not an anomaly. It also makes it easier to compare with alternatives.

Comment: It sounds like 'more efficient' is referring to space on disk and not execution time in this context.

Comment: A useful reference may be [PEP 307](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0307/) where the addition of Pickle protocol 2 is described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the documentation talks about "new-style classes" it (probably) refers to user defined new-style classes. And if you do a simple benchmark with them you can see that protocol 2 is two times faster than protocol 0 in dumping them:

```
>>> import cPickle
>>> import timeit
>>> class MyObject(object):
...     def __init__(self, val):
...             self.val = val
...     def method(self):
...             print self.val
... 
>>> timeit.timeit('cPickle.dumps(MyObject(100), 0)', 'from __main__ import cPickle, MyObject')
17.654622077941895
>>> timeit.timeit('cPickle.dumps(MyObject(100), 1)', 'from __main__ import cPickle, MyObject')
14.536609172821045
>>> timeit.timeit('cPickle.dumps(MyObject(100), 2)', 'from __main__ import cPickle, MyObject')
8.885567903518677
```

Also loading results in a 2x speed up:

```
>>> dumped = cPickle.dumps(MyObject(100), 0)
>>> timeit.timeit('cPickle.loads(dumped)', 'from __main__ import cPickle, dumped')
4.6161839962005615
>>> dumped = cPickle.dumps(MyObject(100), 1)
>>> timeit.timeit('cPickle.loads(dumped)', 'from __main__ import cPickle, dumped')
4.351701021194458
>>> dumped = cPickle.dumps(MyObject(100), 2)
>>> timeit.timeit('cPickle.loads(dumped)', 'from __main__ import cPickle, dumped')
2.3936450481414795
```

In your special case it might be the opposite but we can't say anything without the code that defines `fetch_sku2spu_dict` etc. The only thing I may assume is that the returned value is a `dict`, but in that case protocol 2 is about 6 times faster:

```
>>> mydict = dict(zip(range(100), range(100)))
>>> timeit.timeit('cPickle.dumps(mydict, 0)', 'from __main__ import cPickle, mydict')
46.335021018981934
>>> timeit.timeit('cPickle.dumps(mydict, 1)', 'from __main__ import cPickle, mydict')
7.913743019104004
>>> timeit.timeit('cPickle.dumps(mydict, 2)', 'from __main__ import cPickle, mydict')
7.798863172531128
```

And it's about 2.5 times faster on loading:

```
>>> dumped = cPickle.dumps(mydict, 0)
>>> timeit.timeit('cPickle.loads(dumped)', 'from __main__ import cPickle, dumped')
32.81050395965576
>>> dumped = cPickle.dumps(mydict, 1)
>>> timeit.timeit('cPickle.loads(dumped)', 'from __main__ import cPickle, dumped')
13.997781038284302
>>> dumped = cPickle.dumps(mydict, 2)
>>> timeit.timeit('cPickle.loads(dumped)', 'from __main__ import cPickle, dumped')
14.006750106811523
```

---

On the other side, when using the python version of the module I found out that:

```
>>> mydict = dict(zip(range(100), range(100)))
>>> timeit.timeit('pickle.dumps(mydict,0)', 'from __main__ import pickle, mydict', number=10000)
2.9552500247955322
>>> timeit.timeit('pickle.dumps(mydict,1)', 'from __main__ import pickle, mydict', number=10000)
3.831756830215454
>>> timeit.timeit('pickle.dumps(mydict,2)', 'from __main__ import pickle, mydict', number=10000)
3.842888116836548
```

So it seems like dumping built-in objects with protocol 1 and 2 is slower than using protocol 0 with the python version. But when loading objects protocol 0 is again the slowest of the three:

```
>>> dumped = pickle.dumps(mydict, 0)
>>> timeit.timeit('pickle.loads(dumped)', 'from __main__ import pickle, dumped', number=10000)
2.988792896270752
>>> dumped = pickle.dumps(mydict, 1)
>>> timeit.timeit('pickle.loads(dumped)', 'from __main__ import pickle, dumped', number=10000)
1.2793281078338623
>>> dumped = pickle.dumps(mydict, 2)
>>> timeit.timeit('pickle.loads(dumped)', 'from __main__ import pickle, dumped', number=10000)
1.5425071716308594
```

As you can see by the above mini-benchmarks the time taken to pickle depends on a number of factors, from the type of object you are pickling to which version of the pickle module you use. Without further information we wont be able to explain why in your case protocol 2 is so much slower.